# replacement of create_symlink in windows

Tags: windows, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

currently I am using WSL to develop project, which is original in linux based project. I noticed create_symlink in cmake might produce problems in windows.

1. in linux : fine of course.
2. in WSL : seems fine, can see a symbolic link by type `ls -al` and can `cd` to the folder. Let's say folderA
3. using windows OS to check the folderA, it's just a file in file browser and cannot access it or enter the folder.

Also find some discussion from the internet, but I would like to know if there is anything that's a good replacement for `create_symlink` in windows?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with CMake 3.13 ([Release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/release/3.13.html?highlight=release%20notes#id8)) this should work on Windows too.

If you need to support older versions of CMake, you can use the `mklink` command from the command line on Windows.
But be aware, the `mklink` command expects Windows paths (separated with `\`) so you need to convert your CMake paths to native paths. See the following snippet:

```
if (UNIX)
    execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E create_symlink "${_sourceDirectory}" "${_destinationDirectory}")
else()
    file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${_destinationDirectory}" _dstDir)
    file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${_sourceDirectory}" _srcDir)
    execute_process(COMMAND cmd.exe /c mklink /J "${_dstDir}" "${_srcDir}")
endif()
```

Comment: The create_symlink command does work on Windows. However, I'm on a new machine and now it fails because of insufficient permissions despite having an admin account.

Your solution however still works because of the /J switch, which creates a "junction" link. Apparently not quite the same as a symlink, but it's good enough for me.

So with that said I suppose your solution should still be preferred even for CMake >= 3.13 unless a symlink is really needed over a junction link.